# ViewPager2 always goes to first item on first click

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, android-jetpack-navigation

So in this app, from an "info list" fragment they're presented with a list of dogs (dog0, dog1, dog2, etc). They can then click on a *dog* to go to a details-screen of that *dog* and then be able to swipe left & right to the other *dogs* in the list.

Problem is, (on fresh app opening) the first click (not matter the item) will always go to dog0. They can still swipe to the right to go up the list of the dogs if they'd like.

If they go back to the list screen and then click any *dog* (dog3, dog17, etc), it will then go to that dog. Basically once that pagerFragment has been opened once upon app opening, it will then always go to the desired *dog*, but the first click once the app has been opened will always go to the first *dog* in the list.

Why is it doing this and how can it be resolved?

**method to launch into dog pager fragment**

```
  private void navigateToDog(FragmentActivity fa, final int pos, final List<String> iDs) {
    setDogList(fa, new myApp().getDatabase().dogDao().getDogListByIdArray(iDs));
    DogPagerFragment.currentPosition = pos;
    new AppExecutors().mainThread().execute(() -> {
      Navigation.findNavController(fa, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(
          InfoPagerFragmentDirections.actionInfoPagerFragmentToDogPagerFragment());
    });
  }
```

**DogPagerFragment**

```
public class DogPagerFragment extends Fragment {

  public static int currentPosition;
  
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewPager2 viewPager = (ViewPager2) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.activity_fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    setViewPager(viewPager);
    return viewPager;
  }

  private void setViewPager(ViewPager2 viewPager) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(new DogPagerAdapter(this.getActivity()));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition, false);
    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPosition = position;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**DogPagerAdapter**

```
public class DogPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

  public DogPagerAdapter (FragmentActivity fa) {
    super(fa);
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return DogFragment.forDog(DogListData.itemList.get(position).getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return DogListData.itemList.size();
  }
}
```

**DogFragment**

```
public class DogFragmentextends Fragment {

  private static final String KEY_ID = "dog_id";
  private DogFragmentBinding mBinding;
  private DogDynamicListAdapter mAdapter;

  public static DogFragment forDog(int id) {
    final DogFragment fragment = new DogFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_ID, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.dog_fragment, container, false);
    mAdapter = new DogDynamicListAdapter(
        new StringClickMethods().getArrayCallback(getLifecycle(), requireActivity()));
    mBinding.dogDetails.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return mBinding.getRoot();
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final DogViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DogViewModel.class);
    model.setId(requireArguments().getInt(KEY_ID));
    mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner());
    mBinding.setDogViewModel(model);

    setDetailList(model.getDog());
  }

  private void setDetailList(LiveData<DogItemDetails> value) {
    value.observe(
        getViewLifecycleOwner(),
        dog -> {
          if (dog != null) {
            mAdapter.sendDogStuff(new DogFragmentMethods().getKVPair(dog));
          }
          mBinding.executePendingBindings();
        });
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyView() {
    mBinding = null;
    mAdapter = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
  }
}
```

I think this should include the right code sections to help diagnose.

Comment: Where is the DogFragment? Is `forDog` a constructor?

Comment: @CoryRoy updated question with DogFragment. It includes forDog method

Comment: I think you also need to parse the arguments in `onResume`, the fragment can be reused and you only parse them on onViewCreated()

Comment: So basically, The code viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition, false) in DogPagerFragment just didn't work?

Comment: @Harvey no.... technically. It only works the second "time" it's clicked. So when the app is opened, and you click an item in the list it will always go to the first item. If you then go back and click an item in the list, it will then go to that item.